# Closing hamburger menu on icon, onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a hamburger menu, which is opening fine. I want it to close when i click again on the hamburger menu icon (this is not working, and im struggling). (it closes only if i click a link or click outside the menu).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top border-bottom border-grey">

     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logomob.png"></a>

     <button class="navbar-toggler border-0" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#inicio">ÍNICIO</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a>
  </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

A way to do it, is to change 
data-toogle="dropdown" to data-toogle="collapse", 
but that way, clicking outside the menu or a link, the menu does not close.

I want to close the menu in the hamburger menu icon, but when i click, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using any framework for hamburger menu? or is it part of bootstrap?

Comment: Could you edit this so it's a working code snippet?

Comment: @Farhad its bootstrap.

Comment: @theblackips im sorry, im new to this, how can i do that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, by default you should have the close capability in Hamburger menu button.

### How are you handling this statement?

> "it closes only if i click a link or click outside the menu"

### Setup Bootstrap Menu.

```
<nav class="navbar">

  <!-- Navbar brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
        class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>

  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Links -->

  </div>
  <!-- Collapsible content -->

</nav>
```

### Example

```js
$(document).on('click',function(){
   $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <div class="pos-f-t">
      <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <div class="bg-dark p-4">
          <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
          <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't change data-toggle=dropdown to data-toggle=collapse. I mean, that fixes the problem, but then the menu wont close after i click a link on the Collapsible content and wont closer outside the menu.

Comment: Change it to `collapse.` then write a custom JS to do the outside close collapse. I have updated the code.

Comment: @Farhad update your snippet to reflect the working code. As of now, the menu does not collapse if you click outside of the drop down.

Comment: disinfor Updated. @RicardoSnaw run the code and see.

Comment: I am new to this, and i was putting my JS code before the script of bootstrap, so it wasnt loading it, i had the solution all along, was just a organization error... Thank you guys

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask, just be specific as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, change data-toggle="dropdown" to data-toggle="collapse"

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logomob.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#inicio" ">ÍNICIO</a>
    </li>
    <li class=" nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't change data-toggle=dropdown to data-toggle=collapse. I mean, that fixes the problem, but then the menu wont close after i click a link on the Collapsible content and wont closer outside the menu.